# Meteor - Package for drag and drop data change

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have a three column layout filled with cards, and I want to make it so that if the user drags a card from column 1 to column 2, a field called "status" in the database for that card will switch from "1" to "2". Dragging back to column 1 would change the card "status" field back to "1". Is there a package or best practice to tackle this with Meteor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this very simply with jQuery UI. We have used exactly this principle when we built the fridge for the book Meteor in Action: https://github.com/meteorinaction/ch02-fridge/blob/master/myFridge/myFridge.js

What you need is to define each card as draggable and the columns to be droppable containers. Then all it takes is a single block like that for each column (assuming you place each column in its own template):

```
Template.column2.rendered = function () {
    $('#column2').droppable({
        drop: function (evt, ui) {
            var query = {_id: $(ui.draggable).data('id')};
            var data = {$set: {status: 2}};
            Cards.update(query, data);
        }
    });
};
```

In order for this to work well you need jQuery UI. Then each column would need to be a container that supports droppable cards (which need to be draggable). Each column has an ID (here column2). The actual data is set in the `Cards.update` line. The `data` variable makes handling the update statement a bit easier. Check out the code for the [chapter 2 in the github repo](https://github.com/meteorinaction/ch02-fridge/) to see how it was done for the fride, which is basically a two-column example for your exact scenario.